# SQL command not properly ended

Tags: sql, oracle, spring-boot

I get this error in the spring boot application for the below query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ACTIONS 
WHERE (var1 LIKE %:query% OR var2 LIKE %:query%) AND (ACTION IN :actions OR :length = 0) AND (code = :code)
```

how can I solve it?

This query was working fine, but today it is broken

Comment: What changed since yesterday?

Comment: I have voted to have this closed. This is no valid Oracle query, but you say it ran fine. Now you say it's broken, but you don't tell us the exact error. MT0 posted an answer, but again, you are not giving us any information as to what happens exactly.

Comment: calm down! it was working a month ago. but now, it returns this error "ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended". but my query is the same.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a native SQL statement (and not something that you are running through a pre-processor) then you need to concatenate the `%` literal (which needs to be `'%'`) with your bind variables (and using `ACTION IN :actions` is the same as `ACTION = :actions` as a bind variable is a singular value):

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM   ACTIONS 
WHERE  (var1 LIKE '%' || :query || '%' OR var2 LIKE '%' || :query || '%')
AND    (ACTION = :actions OR :length = 0)
AND    (code = :code)
```

However, if `:actions` is supposed to be a delimited list then that will not work and you need to match on sub-string (with surrounding delimiters). So if you are passing a comma-delimited list:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM   ACTIONS 
WHERE  (var1 LIKE '%' || :query || '%' OR var2 LIKE '%' || :query || '%')
AND    (','||:actions||',' LIKE '%,'||ACTION||',%' OR :length = 0)
AND    (code = :code)
```

Comment: it's not working

Comment: @sayedalimusaviKhoeini "It's not working" is not a constructive statement as it does not tell us: why it is not working; what the errors you are getting are; or what you expect to happen. I suggest you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74906274/edit) and provide a [MRE] with more details of the problem and of the errors you are getting.

Comment: my error is "ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended". but it was working. my query is the same. But after many tries and failures, I finally discovered it has a problem with `Pageable`. but what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

after I checked, I discovered that my oracle DB version is old but my application driver is up to date for this reason it didn't support the pageable. after of update my DB my query has worked very well.

pageable is for version 12 and above.